# returning a local char array with `std::string` return type

Tags: c++, string

In a code review, I found something along these lines:

```
std::string foo()
{
    char tmp[] = "abcd";

    return tmp;
}
```

Is the character buffer converted into a `std::string` before it gets out of scope ?

Comment: That is indeed what happens. Nothing much else to say.

Comment: An `std::string` is constructed using the `char` array before it goes out of scope.

Comment: If it didn't, you would never be able to return a local variable which would make the language kind of useless.

Comment: With `RVO` enabled, it _may_ be better to use an `std::string` instead of a `char` array in the first place. Though whether or not i'd bother saying that on a code review depends on whether or not you have guarantees of rvo being enabled with whichever compilers you're using, and whether or not there's good support for copy elision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the character buffer converted into a std::string before it gets out of scope ?

Yes. The the return value is initialized before the function returns.